# Looping Android Animation - Three buttons showing up and disappearing one after another at the same spot

Tags: android, android-animation

I have the following fragment that gets loaded when my app is first launched.
It simply shows a button that looks like a banner and prompts the user to take a specific action.

Now, this button fades in and out in a 3 second period.

The button is color purple, but what I'd like to do, is make it fade in and out 3 times, purple first, then blue, then green. ( I have two more buttons/banners that I wanted to use. )

> Purple button : 3sec fadein/fadeout + 6sec wait
>  Blue button :
>   3sec wait + 3sec fadein/fadeout + 3sec wait
>  Green button : 6sec
>   wait + 3 sec fadein/fadeout

All that in an endless circle.
How could I do that?

```
public class StartFragment extends Fragment
{
    AlphaAnimation fadeIn = new AlphaAnimation(0.0f , 1.0f );

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.start, container, false);
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

        Button scanBanner = (Button) getView().findViewById(R.id.ScanBanner);

        fadeIn.setDuration(1500);

        scanBanner.startAnimation(fadeIn);

        fadeIn.setRepeatCount(Animation.INFINITE);
        fadeIn.setRepeatMode(Animation.REVERSE);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add an animation listener to change the color.  Take care to only change color every second repeat to account for fading back out to zero first.

```
fadeIn.setAnimationListener(new AnimationListener() {
    private int cycle = 0;
    public void onAnimationRepeat() {
        cycle = (cycle + 1) % 6;
        if (cycle == 0) {
            scanBanner.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.purple);
        } else if (cycle == 2) {
            scanBanner.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.blue);
        } else if (cycle == 4) {
            scanBanner.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.green);
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer, can you help me a little bit more? How would you implement this in the code above?